# Fragment menu item displayed after a second tab is selected

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have an activity with 3 tabs. I've used ActionBar.Tab class to add this tabs. Each of this tabs contain a fragment - and in this fragment I've added a menu overriding onCreateOptionsMenu.

When I open this activity the menu items are displayed only after I manually select a second tab, and after that the items are displayed as they should.

Can anyone please explain to my why this weird behavior and how I can overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling onCreateOptionsMenu in your activity?
It might be that it is not called until you start the second fragment so the menu is not inflated yet.

Comment: No - I need that each fragment have a different menu and implementation...so having the onCreateOptionsMenu in activity will  not work

Comment: So just invalidate options menu in your fragment and recreate the specific one, but first create it in the activity, so it can be inflated on start.

Comment: I dont exactly understand what are you talking about